# How can I properly open new form and close existing form without any error?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login form and when I click login, it opens the new form. On the new form when I click a button to open another form, it shows errors.
I tried to use this.hide() or even this.close(), but it shows two errors and 10 warnings. 
error 1 : The process cannot access the file .. because it is being used by another process.
error 2 : Exceeded retry count of 10. The file is locked by ...

```
// btnLogin on login form
this.hide();
frm2 f2 = new frm2();
f2.show();

// btnNew on frm2
this.hide();
frm3 f3 = new frm3();
f3.show();
```

Comment: The error is probably not related to the "problem" you describe, what does your 3rd form do?

Comment: It like I have 3 forms. The first one is login and the second is the lists of button which I can click to open another form to do specific task. the second form is like a toolbar.

Comment: Does your 3rd form use files?

Comment: No. I didn't write anything yet on my third form.

Comment: Since you're talking about warnings, is that error shown in the Output window of Visual Studio and not actually when you're running the application?

Comment: It shows when I run the program.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Which line of code gives the error? Do you have any code `frm2` which uses file?

Comment: You don't have the program running, when you (re)compile, do you? It looks like you do. Then the compiler cannot access the exe file as it's in use. Close it before (re)compiling.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I did, but it showed error before debug. frm2 didn't use file.

Comment: @stickybit I did it by killing the process in task manager. I don't know why it still in use because I close the program already. One more thing if it's working and I change this.hide to this.close, I got the same error.

Comment: Looks like the project is not exiting at all.. you are hiding the forms. So frm1 and frm2 are opened and hidden. When you close frm3 the other forms are still there in hidden state.. that's why when you open the application again you will see the error. When you close the frm3, what do you want to happen? How are you closing the frm3?

Comment: I use this.close() on frm3 when closing the form

Comment: It is a build error, not a compile error or runtime error.  Use Task Manager to ensure the program isn't still running.  Next temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to show the New Form then you have to hide the existing form.

```
// btnLogin on login form

frm2 f2 = new frm2();
f2.show();
this.hide();


// btnNew on frm2

frm3 f3 = new frm3();
f3.show();
this.hide();
```